# How to exclude the default rule when printing out rules in Orange CN2 rule learner?

Tags: python, orange

When printing out rules in Orange CN2 rule learner using the rule_to_string() function, sometimes the default rule is also printed. How to exclude the default rule when printing out rules? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply filter out such rules:

```
for r in rules:
    if len(r.filter.conditions) > 0:
        # print rule
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution!